# How to get same results of Wilcoxon sign rank test in R and SAS

Tags: r, sas

R code:

```
x <- c(9, 5, 9 ,10, 13, 8, 8, 13, 18, 30)
y <- c(10, 6, 9, 8, 11, 4, 1, 3, 3, 10)
library(exactRankTests)
wilcox.exact(y,x, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")
```

The results: V = 3, p-value = 0.01562

SAS code:

```
data aaa;
  set aaa;
  diff=x-y;
run;
proc univariate;
  var diff;
run;
```

The results: S=19.5    Pr >= |S|   0.0156

How to get statistics S in R?

If n<=20 the exact P was same in SAS and R,but if n>20 the results were different.

```
x <- c(9, 5, 9 ,10, 13, 8, 8, 13, 18, 30,9, 5, 9 ,10, 13, 8, 8, 13, 18, 30,9,11,12,10)
y <- c(10, 6, 9, 8, 11, 4, 1, 3, 3, 10,10, 6, 9, 8, 11, 4, 1, 3, 3, 10,10,12,11,12)
wilcox.exact(y,x,paired=TRUE, alternative = "two.sided",exact = FALSE)
```

The results: V = 34, p-value = 0.002534

The SAS results:S=92.5    Pr >= |S|   0.0009

How to get the same statistics S and P value in SAS and R? Thank you!

Comment: The [online SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect029.htm) says that SAS doesn't do an exact test for n>= 20 ...

Comment: This is how R calculates the "V" statistics (assuming no missing values): `a<-y-x;a <- a[a != 0];r <- rank(abs(a));sum(r[a > 0])`. You'll have to read the SAS documentation to see how is calculates `S`

Comment: Also, you seem to have the parameters in different order between programs. You pass `(y,x)` to R so it calculates first-minus-second parameter (or `y-x` in your case) and you're doing `x-y` in SAS>

Comment: The results were different in SAS and R when n>= 20.

Comment: @MrFlick The P value was same when use (y,x) and (y,x) in R.

Comment: @stats You wanted to get the same statistics, right? The p-values may be the same but the test statistics might not be. I'm just telling you how that "V" value in R is calculated.